# explain this line of code (lists)

Tags: python

```
print ( [ 2 ∗ [ k ] for k in range ( 3 ) ] [ 2 ] [ 1 ] )
```

this is the code and it says the answer is 2, will someone explain it to me. i don't understand exactly what the code is asking for and i don't know how it is getting 2 as an answer i'm assuming it has something to do with the iteration but i don't really fully understand it. i have a lot of difficulty with lists in general and this was a question that was both on the practice exam and the real exam and i want to understand it

Comment: Times like this when one wishes for the old "too localized" close reason. Is it really useful to have a knowledge base full of "explain what this does" questions?

Answer (score 2):

`for k in range(3)` will set `k` to `0`, then `1`, then `2`. So then `2*[k]` will make a list with two elements where each element is the current value of `k`. The result after the list comprehension is equivalent to  `[ [0,0], [1,1], [2,2] ][2][1]` Since the `[2]` after the list comprehension will access the 3rd element of the list (the list at index 2), and the `[1]` will access the second element of the sublist, the result is `2`

```
    0      1      2     <-- first level indices 

[ [0,0], [1,1], [2,2] ]
                   ^--- this is the item you get 
   0 1    0 1    0 1    <-- second level indices
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break the single statement into 4 actually and it will make more sense naturally.

```
>>> range ( 3 )
[0, 1, 2]
>>> [ 2 * [ k ] for k in [0, 1, 2] ] # where 2*[0] returns [0,0] and so on
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
>>> [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]][2]
[2, 2]
>>> [2, 2][1]
2
```